# How to handle user-input typos when writing a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database, I have cities and states that (appear to be) are stored from user input. I am trying to get only distinct locations, so my query looks like this:

```
SELECT Distinct C.City, C.State FROM Customers C
```

The problem I ran into is that some cities have typos, so in my results there could be "Dallas" TX, "Dalas" TX, "Dallas," TX, and so on. Is there a way to filter for the "correct" spelling without having to sort through ten thousand rows?

Comment: Well your problem isn't DB, Your problem is your data entry. Use dropdown combos to enter things like City and State. Don't allow user introduce typos.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a spell check. You could load a table with every city in the US and then join against that to check for correct spelling. Or control the data input and don't allow free text.

Comment: You need a better data model. You are dealing with customers, states, and cities. I see a customer table, but where are the states and city tables?

Comment: Simple answer NO. Entering states in a free text is the wrong design, and now you know why. It should be a list that the user must select from. As for the city, it is debatable because there are so many cities to put in a list. Most websites let the user enter it in a free text, but then some websites validate it using the postal data. For your case, someone has to go through all the records and fix the data. Or, you'll have to build a small app that validates all records against the postal data.

Comment: I did not create the tables or the front side, I am just working on a project that uses this data.

Comment: That's a major, major problem imo. There may be some things you can do to try to fix, but I think those might be outside the scope of one measly SO question.

Comment: In my opinion there is nothing you can really do about this. Don't try to apply fuzzy logic here. "Horseshoe, NC" is actually another place than "Horse Shoe, NC". So treat differently stored places as different places. If they want to do something about typos and the like, tell them to change the database accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems like a huge problem. If you have ZIP codes, you can enrich the data. But judging by your question, this is not the case.

I think you might import a table with unique states and cities and join this table to your table. The non-matching rows might be checked and updated. Still an awful job though.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're design should be addressed, storing free text cities and states tends to produce issues...well, like this.  If you can address the design, do so...if you are forced to work with this, then I'm afraid you are in for some manual fun.

Create a table as city,state,equivlent_city, equivlent_state

Select all distinct values from city/state from your table and export them into a spreadsheet (copy and paste works too).  Go through each line in this spreadsheet and assign the proper spelling to each city state that you want it to appear under...ya, this can be a long tedious process (last time I did this, I delegated this fantastic task to the summer students).  When you're done, import the spreadsheet back into your database as a table.  Anytime you need to refer to the city/state from your fact table, join to this translation table on city and state, then refer to equivalent_city and equivalent_state in youre queries.

Advantage to this method is this translation table grows as your users find new and interesting ways to spells cities (you will need a process to continue to update this table with new spellings)....there is an upper limit on screwy spellings out there and you'll eventually capture the majority of them.  Disadvantage is in maintaining the setup (and the disbelief that even though you thought you had all spellings of Dallas tx captured, some user will input 'Daalass tex').

Alternative is stated in the comments, better design prevents this horrible solution from being needed.